# zsh: command not found tickets (macOS)

Tags: npm, command, zsh

first of all, I'm not really good into this, but I installed something with npm.

```
npm i tickets
npm install -g tickets
```

Installation was succesfull and it worked fine. Afterwards, I wanted to look into the sourcecode to find sth. I needed to edit. I open the folder "tickets" into visual studio code and searched through the sourcecode but couldn't find it. Then I wanted to start it again and then it started - getting this error:

```
zsh: command not found: tickets
```

When I was working in visual studio code I was in the "tickets" directory. So, like in the beginning when It worked, I switched to home directory but I still keep getting the error. I have no idea why it doesn't work not. Basically, I did nothing except being in a different directory.

I tried to fix it with exporting the path (using a MacBook):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$HOME/npm/bin
```

But did not work out.

I'm struggling now by testing out different solutions I found. Hope someone can help me out in a noob-friendly way! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`npm i` installs a package in the current project. If you want it to be available from anywhere, you need to install it globally - `npm install -g tickets` (you'll probably need `sudo` in order to do that, though).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I also did it with "npm install - g tickets", but still "command not found"

Comment: If you invoke a program, say `tickets`, my just typing its name, the command must be found in one of the directories in your PATH variable, and must have execution rights (x-bit being set). Did you verify this?